# Simple quiz program in Python3

Tags: python

I was thinking on how to create a small program which asks for the capital of a country. I decided to store the countries in a tuple because they won't change:

```
countries = ("australia", "france", "egypt")
```

Each time the program executes I want to see the same question but a different country. "What's the capital of Australia?" or "What's the capital of France?", etc... Something like this:

```
import random

random_num = random.randint(0, len(countries) - 1)

user_input = input("What's the capital of " +
                   countries[random_num].title() + "? ")
```

I created another tuple to store the answers, but they need to be in the same index position order as the countries:

```
countries = ("australia", "france", "egypt") # index 0 matches index 0 in capitals,...
capitals = ("canberra", "paris", "cairo")
```

Then I ca do an IF:

```
if user_input.lower() == capitals[random_num]:
    print("Correct!")
else:
    print("No. Try again!")
```

Do you think it is better to use a dictionary and do a match based on a key/value pair? I would be grateful for any suggestions or ideas, not necessary code. Thank you.

Comment: a `{country:capital}` dict seems like the best approach, yes

Comment: And then you can use `city = random.choice(list(d.keys()))` to select the city

Comment: I think https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would be better place for this

Comment: Thanks lazarus! I didn't know about that page.